# Suppressing an Aura?

Tags: dnd-4e

I have a 4e dnd character that has the lich template.  Can I suppress the necrotic aura, and if so what kind of action is it?  Ive looked elsewhere and I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere that explains auras for PC's.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From DDI glossary definition of [Aura](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=344):

> **Deactivating an Aura:** A creature can take a minor action to deactivate or reactivate one of its auras. However, certain auras have set durations and cannot be reactivated after they end.